# Xamarin чтение внедренного текстового файла

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Есть коллекция в текстовом файле. Прикрепил её к приложению и пытаюсь прочитать.
Код взял из примера на странице майкрософт.
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#feedback

```
var assembly = 
IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(LoadResourceText)).Assembly;
Stream stream 
=assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WorkingWithFiles.LibTextResource.txt");
string text = "";
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (stream))
{  
text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Видео как не работает после 10 минуты.

https://youtu.be/bYlOvAThnDs

Нужно считать данные построчно и добавить в коллекцию.
Но пишет, что ошибка:
system.argumentnullexception: "Value cannot be null.Arg_ParamName_Name"

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы если свое приложение называете `App255555` ну так и используйте его в пути к файлу.

```
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("App255555.myfile.txt");
```

И на будущее.

- В вопросе, для демонстрации проблемы, надо использовать свой проблемный код, а не нудное кино под названием "Неловкие приемы для создания неработающего кода".
- Вам надо изучить как производить отладку своего кода, что такое точка остановки, движение по коду, отслеживание значений локальных переменных. Все эти навыки вам бы очень помогли в случае вот таких вот ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не заметил этот момент  с автопереводчиком.